# MySQL into iOS Application (Xcode 5)

Tags: mysql, ios, uitableview, xcode5

I am new to app making, but I have a small tech review site that I am trying to grow and I want to make an app for. Its pretty simple what I am setting up. To start, I am using MySQL to have three basic things. The review's picture, the title, and the review itself. The idea of this is so I can have other users log in to write reviews and it can load easily on an app, the website, etc... The most trouble I am having is in Xcode trying to make an app for this. I want two basic screens. A list of all the reviews with the picture on the left, and the title, and when you click on it, it takes you to the second screen displaying the review itself. Does that make sense?

(I am using Xcode 5 on Mac OS X 10.9. This App is intended for iOS)

-Thank You!

*Moderators, I apologize if this is a duplicate question, I have searched and have not found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what is your asking then you probably need to rephrase the question and edit the tags. Because it has nothing to do with xcode5, mysql, uitableview or even iOS.

Before you start designing your iOS app, you need to think the overall architecture for your service. The client iOS app shouldn't (and usually can't) communicate directly with a database server (mysql in your case), you need to think about a server side API layer for your iOS app to consume.

You need to outline your [web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API) and decide what is its interface (entry points, resources, data structures), take a look at [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) architecture, for example. Decide on your data exchange format (e.g. [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), XML). Then decide what platform and framework you want to create your API layer with (e.g. PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Asp.net etc).

Your iOS app itself sounds like a simple classic [Master-Detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93detail_interface) pattern and what you wrote is a good start (Google for master detail examples, plenty of them for iOS as well). Your question is too broad here, you need to be more specific in order for people to be able to help you with the app itself.